# Xcode 7.3 errors while compiling ZXingObjC code for QRCode generation

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code, zxing, xcode7.3

I am using ZXingObjC library for creating and reading QRCode in may application and was working fine.

Recently I updated Xcode to 7.3(7D175) and created a new project and imported the same files for generating QRCode. But now I am not able to compile the project and is getting quite a lot number of errors.

Some errors are described below:

```
1.ZXingObjC/core/ZXResultPoint.h:21:37: No type or protocol named 'NSCopying'
2.ZXingObjC/core/ZXResultPoint.h:21:28: Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'ZXResultPoint'
3. Expected a type -> + (void)orderBestPatterns:(NSMutableArray *)patterns;
4.  ZXingObjC/common/ZXBitArray.h:28:41: Unknown type name 'int32_t' for @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) int32_t *bits;
5. ZXingObjC/common/ZXBitMatrix.h:31:26: Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'ZXBitMatrix' @interface ZXBitMatrix : NSObject <NSCopying>
```

Can anybody help me in resolving these errors? Any idea ???

Thanks,

AKC

Comment: Have you done a complete build after the update? (not just run)

Comment: Yes ... I have done a completed Clean and Run the project. But errors are coming ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had similar issue once I created a new Project using Xcode 7.3 and then importing ZXingObjC library. I just imported Foundation Framework class and then all the errors was cleared.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

So just **import Foundation Framework and it will work** for sure.